# How to list services in cygwin?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, cygwin

I want to remove/uninstall cygwin completely from my system. How can I list and kill all the services in cygwin before deleting all the folders? I tried cygrunsrv -L, but it is not working. Any suggestion would be appreciable.

I want to remove from windows XP professional, service pack 3.

Answer (score 3):

Have you already tried to follow [this](http://cygwin.com/faq-nochunks.html#faq.setup.uninstall-all)?

> How do I uninstall all of Cygwin?
>
> - Setup has no automatic uninstall facility. The recommended method to
>     remove all of Cygwin is as follows:
> - If you have any Cygwin services running, remove by repeating the
>     instructions in
>     http://cygwin.com/faq/faq.html#faq.setup.uninstall-service for all
>     services that you installed. Common services that might have been
>     installed are sshd, cron, cygserver, inetd, apache, postgresql, and so
>     on.
> - Stop the X11 server if it is running, and terminate any Cygwin
>     programs that might be running in the background. Exit the command
>     prompt and ensure that no Cygwin processes remain. Note: If you want
>     to save your mount points for a later reinstall, first save the output
>     of mount -m as described at
>     http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-utils.html#mount.
> - If you installed cyglsa.dll by running the shell script
>     /usr/bin/cyglsa-config as described in
>     http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/ntsec.html, then you need to configure
>     Windows to stop using the LSA authentication package. You do so by
>     editing the registry and restoring
>     /HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SYSTEM/CurrentControlSet/Control/Lsa/Authentication
>     Packages back to it's original value of msv1_0, and then rebooting.
> - Delete the Cygwin root folder and all subfolders. If you get an error
>     that an object is in use, then ensure that you've stopped all services
>     and closed all Cygwin programs. If you get a 'Permission Denied' error
>     then you will need to modify the permissions and/or ownership of the
>     files or folders that are causing the error. For example, sometimes
>     files used by system services end up owned by the SYSTEM account and
>     not writable by regular users.
> - The quickest way to delete the entire tree if you run into this
>     problem is to change the ownership of all files and folders to your
>     account. To do this in Windows Explorer, right click on the root
>     Cygwin folder, choose Properties, then the Security tab. If you are
>     using Windows XP Home or Simple File Sharing, you will need to boot
>     into Safe Mode to access the Security tab. Select Advanced, then go to
>     the Owner tab and make sure your account is listed as the owner.
>     Select the 'Replace owner on subcontainers and objects' checkbox and
>     press Ok. After Explorer applies the changes you should be able to
>     delete the entire tree in one operation. Note that you can also
>     achieve this in Cygwin by typing chown -R user / or by using other
>     tools such as CACLS.EXE.
> - Delete the Cygwin shortcuts on the Desktop and Start Menu, and
>     anything left by setup-x86{_64}.exe in the download directory.
>     However, if you plan to reinstall Cygwin it's a good idea to keep your
>     setup-x86{_64}.exe download directory since you can reinstall the
>     packages left in its cache without redownloading them.
> - If you added Cygwin to your system path, you should remove it unless
>     you plan to reinstall Cygwin to the same location. Similarly, if you
>     set your CYGWIN environment variable system-wide and don't plan to
>     reinstall, you should remove it.
> - Finally, if you want to be thorough you can delete the registry tree
>     Software\Cygwin under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE and/or HKEY_CURRENT_USER.
>     However, if you followed the directions above you will have already
>     removed everything important. Typically only the installation
>     directory has been stored in the registry at all.

Comment: I tried, but I have no clue how to remove all the services. before proceeding with other steps.

Comment: Added to that I am not able to list all the services available in cygwin.